# Only display posts after current date

Tags: posts, custom-field, filters, query

All my posts have a custom field named `date-start-custom`. The value of the custom field is in the date format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` (e.g: 2021-06-15 14:30), and I want to only list posts that has a date later than the current date.

I am already altering the query to sort the posts from earliest to latest, and I was hoping I could do this in the same query.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts' );
function filter_posts( $query ) {
    if( is_category() && !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page','10' );
        $query->set( 'orderby','meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key','date-start-custom' );
        $query->set( 'order','ASC' );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

I googled this earlier and found [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57979/wp-query-show-posts-that-end-later-than-today) with an answer, but it didn't really work for me. This is the code I tried, which didn't work:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts' );
function filter_posts( $query ) {
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i");
    if( is_category() && !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page','10' );
        $query->set( 'orderby','meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key','date-start-custom' );
        $query->set( 'meta_value', $now );
        $query->set( 'meta_type','DATE' );
        $query->set( 'meta_compare','>=' );
        $query->set( 'order','ASC' );
    }
     return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out `meta_query` was the way to go. This is the code I used to make it work.

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts' );
function filter_posts( $query ) {
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime('+2 hours'));
    if( is_category() && !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page','10' );
        $query->set( 'orderby','meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key','date-start-custom' );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key' => 'date-start-custom',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value' => $now,
                'type' => 'DATE'
            )
        ));
        $query->set( 'order','ASC' );
    }
     return $query;
}
```

Comment: I can't accept this answer yet since my account is brand new, will accept it once I'm able to